# Why does my WebRequest/HttpWebRequest object sometimes require a cast and other times not?

Tags: c#, casting, httpwebrequest, webrequest, compact-framework2.0

I adapted this code from a post by Andy Wiggly (who is not just "some guy" - he co-wrote "MS .NET Compact Framework" for MS Press):

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();
request.ContentType = contentType;
((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = contentType;
((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
((HttpWebRequest)request).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
{
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    request.ContentLength = encoding.GetByteCount(data);
    //request.ContentType = contentType; <= redundant; set above
    request.GetRequestStream().Write(
      encoding.GetBytes(data), 0, (int)request.ContentLength);
    request.GetRequestStream().Close();
}
```

Note how in the first block of code I had to cast "request" as HttpWebRequest; within the conditional, though, casting is unnecessary. Why the difference? Should "WebRequest" be "HttpWebRequest" instead? If I do that, the casting is greyed out, indicating it's unnecessary, but Wiggly must have done that for a reason, and still: why is the casting obviated within the conditional block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpWebRequest.Create() is kind of a static factory. You cannot override the behaviour in a derived class. Depending on the URI you provide, it can create a HttpWebRequest or a FtpWebRequest. Which are derived from WebRequest. When you know you're creating a Http request, then i suggest you do the following:
`HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri)`

or

`var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri)`

When you want to access the special properties/methods of the derived class which aren't available in the base class, you have to do this cast.

e.g. `KeepAlive` is not available in the WebRequest base class because it belongs to HttpWebRequest.
Other properties like `Method` is defined in the base class and therefore you don't need the cast.